# CSDEF and CSPKG file for Azure Website

Tags: azure, msbuild, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

Am new to Azure and Websites.
On Boarded to Azure Cloud Services with CSPKG file.

Am looking to create a package for Websites from the Build and use it later to deploy in my Azure Subscription.

Was wondering if i can have CSPKG file for a Website and how to generate it.
Or is there a better way to package your Azure Website contents ( Without knowing the target where it will be deployed).

**Please Note:** I am aware of FTP, GIT and Deploy directly from Visual Studio.

Want to know the process of getting the package out of MSBuild without targets and Deployment.

Thanks,
Pradeep.

Comment: Azure Web Sites and Azure Cloud Services are different.  Do you really need to use a Cloud Project (which gets deployed as a Cloud Service) or do you just need a Web project (that could be deployed to an Azure web site)?  http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm/

Comment: Thanks for the Repsonse Dave. Am looking to package my web project and use it later for deployments.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Websites does not support CSPKG.

An alternate approach would be a [WebDeploy package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323(v=vs.110).aspx).